OpenCL version checks fail because CL_VERSION_*_* macros are set to 1
The OpenCL documentation states that the CL_VERSION_*_* macros contain integer values that represent the respective OpenCL versions. For example, CL_VERSION_2_0 is supposed to have a value of 200. However, the OpenCL header shows that all of the macros are set to 1:
#if CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION >= 210 && !defined(CL_VERSION_2_1)
#define CL_VERSION_2_1  1
#endif
#if CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION >= 200 && !defined(CL_VERSION_2_0)
#define CL_VERSION_2_0  1
#endif
#if CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION >= 120 && !defined(CL_VERSION_1_2)
#define CL_VERSION_1_2  1

This is causing my checks such as #if __OPENCL_VERSION__ < CL_VERSION_2_0 to fail. Is there a reason for this consistency?

If you need to compare the number, use CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION.  The others are just for yes-or-no comparisons.  It would be redundant to have CL_VERSION_2_0 have the value 200.

In this case, would it make sense to just check for the presence of CL_VERSION_*_* and avoid the use of CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION or __OPENCL_VERSION__ altogether?

Because those #if statements all use >=, the mere presence of CL_VERSION_2_0 means that you have AT LEAST version 2.0, so it's easier than using the comparison.

Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks.
